# bash test injection vulnerability with -v

Tags: bash

One of my bash scripts contains this test:

```
if [ ! -v "$3" ]; then
   exit
else
   ...
fi
```

Is there a way to inject data in $3 argument that will execute something nasty ? (my script is run with suid privilege and contains sensitive variables...)

Thanks

Comment: There's probably a better approach than expecting the caller to know the name of an in-script variable.

Comment: How can the caller see the content of in an in-script variable ?

Comment: What is the `-v` operator supposed to mean? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: The -v is for checking variable existence

Comment: Can you provide a reference to it? I don't see it in the Bash manual.

Comment: @Barmar: This might help: `help test | grep -- -v`

Comment: Anyway, I think the answer to your question is no. Since you quote the variable, nothing in it is executed.

Comment: Since `-v` is a `bash` extension, I would use it with `[[` instead of `[`, even if `bash`'s built-in `[` supports it.

Comment: Your test asks if, say, SOME_VARIABLE_NAME is defined. Why would the caller of the script be expected to know the name of a variable to pass as argument 3, rather than having your script look at the value of `$3` and *it* deciding which variable to use in that case? `case $3 of FOO) var=$SOME_VAR;; BAR) var=$SOME_OTHER_VAR;; esac; # use $var in some way`

Comment: This is a root-me.org challenge ... https://www.root-me.org/fr/Challenges/App-Script/Bash-quoted-expression-injection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is an injection vulnerability here. The problem is that `-v` test evaluates its argument as a variable, and in bash v4.3 and later that can include an array element (e.g. `arrayVar[5]`), and since array indexes (for non-associative arrays) are numbers, the index part gets evaluated as an arithmetic context, which can include command substitutions.

So if `$3` is something like this:

```
x[$(touch /tmp/pwned)]
```

...or, if you're worried about sensitive variables:

```
x[$(echo "$SensitiveVar" >/tmp/pwned)]
```

...it'll wind up executing the part inside `$( )`, with privilege and access to internal shell variables.

Note that since this occurs because of how the `-v` test is evaluated, quoting `$3` doesn't help, and neither does using `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`.

Comment: I can't make this work (bash 4.2)

Comment: @Fravadona Interesting. The `-v` test was added in bash v4.2, but apparently it didn't handle array element references until v4.3 (see the [release announcement](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2014-02/msg00081.html), point "ll."). Therefore, this injection vulnerability only exists under bash v4.3 and later.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer but there is something i do not understand: If i run "./script.sh ... ... "x[$(echo "$SensitiveVar" >/tmp/pwned)]"  : The echo command will be run before script.sh...

Comment: @Bob5421 Your interactive shell expanding (& executing) the `$( )` because it's only in double-quotes. Use single-quotes to keep the interactive shell from expanding it prematurely. See ["Difference between single and double quotes in Bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).

Answer (score 1):

No. Since the variable is quoted, it's simply expanded and the result is treated as a single word in the expansion. No further processing is done with the result. Quoting a variable is the sure way to prevent code injection in shell scripts, unless you pass the expansion to something else that executes it. E.g.

```
ssh hostname "$3"
```

doesn't execute `$3` locally, but the remote server will execute it.

Note that `[ -v "$3" ]` doesn't test whether `$3` is set, it expands `$3`, which should contain the putative variable name, and tests whether *that* variable exists. If you want to know whether `$3` exists, you would have to use `[ -v 3 ]` or `[ $# -ge 3 ]`

Comment: Syntactically you're correct, and while it does answer OPs question, and I agree with your statement(s), I am dubious that this sort of testing is the correct rout.  This seems to be an  [X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: See Gordon's answer. There is an injection vulnerability that can't be addressed just by quoting the variable.